# What is the modern equivalent of "ps aux" on macOS Sierra?

Tags: unix

The BSD backend of MacOS has `ps` built in. The BSD General Commands Manual says that

> The biggest change is in the interpretation of the -u option, which now displays processes belonging to the specified username(s).  Thus, "ps -aux" will fail (unless you want to know about user "x"). As a convenience, however, "ps aux" still works as it did in Tiger.

I am wondering what the current standard is for this—dare I write—*obsolete* command+parameter sequence.

Comment: What's wrong with `ps aux` without minus?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Nothing except that it is deprecated. Read the quote carefully. I assume the reason for its retirement is that it does not follow the standard parameter scheme of `-p` where p is a parameter character. (or `--parameter` where p is spelled out)

Comment: ps aux is BSD syntax. Portable syntax would be ps -ef.

Comment: @fd0 Your comment should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To replicate `ps aux` (BSD style) in the AT&T version of ps, you have to use

```
ps -Ao user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tt,stat,start,time,command
```

This command is compatible with scripts that expect the same output as `ps aux`.

The only difference is the sort order; `ps aux` sorts all processes by their *start time* whereas `ps -Ao` sorts them by *PID*.

---

`ps -jef` is a shorter command, but it will output different headers.:

- USER
- PID
- PPID
- PGID
- SESS
- JOBC
- STAT
- TT
- TIME
- COMMAND
- UID
- C
- STIME
- TTY

Comment: Thanks. "The only difference is the sort order; ps aux sorts all processes by their start time whereas ps -Ao sorts them by PID."  Can `ps --sort bsdstart -Ao` sort in start time?